# how to show toast if auth failed jetpack compose firebase if else @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, toast, android-toast

There appear to be an infinite number of explanations for this error on stackoverflow, none of which address my issue.

I want to show a toast if the authentication failed

I am using firebase auth but the error is with the Location context
[image]

how can I pass through this limitation?

source code for the button

```
  Button(
                    onClick = {
                        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                    navController.navigate(Screen.PreferenceScreen.route)
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        LocalContext.current,
                                        "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show()


                                }
                            }


                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    enabled = isPasswordValid && confirmPassword == password,
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Register")
                }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the `context` outside of the Button, and use it in the Toast like this.

```
@Composable
fun MyButtonWithToast() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
  

    Button(
        onClick = {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Authentication failed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Register")
    }
}
```

or if you have a composable structure, just simply declare it there and pass it in the composable this button is in

```
@Composable
fun SomeParentComposable() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    
    MyButtonWithToast(context = context)
}
```

Comment: thank you i just didnt found the correct Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a Composable function post on stack overflow lol